# Confusing reversed touch event in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

In my function

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    for touch in touches{
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)
        print("X: \(touchLocation.x) Y: \(touchLocation.y)")
    }
}
```

I get reversed Y value. If I click at the top I get ~0 value and if I click at the bottom I get high value. This makes my sprite im moving move in the wrong Y direction.

However if I remove '.view' in self.view it works as it should. Does anyone know why it's reversed when I use self.view?

Comment: What's the type of `self`?

Comment: @dan It is an SKView...

Comment: And this is happening because of a difference between UIKit's and SpriteKit's coordinate system. UIKit has 0,0 in top left corner. So, as OP figured out already, using just self (which is a scene) would work as expected.

Comment: @kraken108 Hey man, have you solve your doubts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by [Whirlwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3402095/whirlwind) in the comment below your question, this happened because with `self` you indicate `SKScene` (SpriteKit) and with `self.view` you use `SKView` (`UIView` subclass so UIKit system):

**UIKit** coordinate system for **iOS** has its origin at the upper left of the drawing area, and positive values extend down and to the right from it.

**SpriteKit** coordinate system uses the same coordinate system on both **iOS** and **OS X**, has the origin (0,0) in the lower-left corner, and the (1334,750) coordinate in the upper-right corner.

Comment: SpriteKit  changed the default size of sks files, it is no longer 1024,768 it is now 750,1334

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you sir, I don't know yet this important info