# Translate location in UIView to SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to use the touchBegan functionality in my UIView and I should trigger SKScene methods. Everything is almost working expect the fact that the startingPosition of my SKNode is different from the touch in the UIView. I read about it here: [Confusing reversed touch event in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172551/confusing-reversed-touch-event-in-swift) however they do not give a solution how to translate a UIView touch gesture to a SKScene touch gesture that correspons with the touch location. This works:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
    var currentPoint = touch.location(in: scene)
    executeSpawningStar(startPosition: currentPoint)
    }
}
```

But I place a UIView above it, and this function does not work anymore. When I change it to this:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
    var currentPoint = touch.location(in: newUIView)
    executeSpawningStar(startPosition: currentPoint)
    }
}
```

The spawning looks very weird. The coordinaties of the spawning star is not correct. How can I transfer the correct coordinates from the UIView to SpriteKit settings to match the real position of the touch gesture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news! SKView has methods for converting to and from SKScene coordinates.

```
func convert(_ point: CGPoint, from scene: SKScene) -> CGPoint
func convert(_ point: CGPoint, to scene: SKScene) -> CGPoint
```

So you could do something like:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        var currentPoint = touch.location(in: newUIView)
        currentPoint = gameScene.convertPoint(fromView: currentPoint)
        executeSpawningStar(startPosition: currentPoint)
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview/1520328-convert
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview/1519847-convert

Comment: Thank you, but how to add that function? Swift is telling me to put a {} with it. When I just the type the line currentPoint = convert(currentPoint, to: gameScene) it says use of unresolved identifier convert. Edit: I got it to work